# I'm using spring, hibernate and mysql. How can I let my app create the table automatically

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, mysql-error-1146

I'm using **spring**, all my annotated entity class information are put in the ApplicationContext.xml. I'm using a MySql database, now how can I use the SchemaExport function in hibernate to create the tables? My application can't create the table automatically, though i have set `<prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>`. This is my ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:///edde" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>com.edde.Book</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
    <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <bean id="bookDao" class="com.edde.BookDao">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="bookService" class="com.edde.BookServiceImpl">
  <property name="dao" ref="bookDao"></property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

This is my test application:

```
package com.edde;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
  BookService service = (BookService) factory.getBean("bookService");

  Book book = new Book();
  book.setBookName("great book");

  service.saveBook(book);

 }

}
```

When I run my app, I get this error:

```
2010-05-20 17:25:20,777 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - 
    /* insert com.edde.Book
        */ insert 
        into
            Book
            (author, bookName, publication) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.edde.Book
        */ insert 
        into
            Book
            (author, bookName, publication) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
2010-05-20 17:25:20,809 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher] - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
2010-05-20 17:25:20,809 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - could not insert: [com.edde.Book] [/* insert com.edde.Book */ insert into Book (author, bookName, publication) values (?, ?, ?)]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'edde.book' doesn't exist
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2696)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2105)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2398)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2316)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2301)
 at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2329)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2836)
 at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:705)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:693)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:689)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:686)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:683)
 at com.edde.BookDao.insertBook(BookDao.java:18)
 at com.edde.BookServiceImpl.saveBook(BookServiceImpl.java:34)
 at com.edde.Test.main(Test.java:17)
2010-05-20 17:25:20,809 WARN [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2010-05-20 17:25:20,809 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - Table 'edde.book' doesn't exist
2010-05-20 17:25:20,809 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils] - Closing Hibernate Session
2010-05-20 17:25:20,809 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager] - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
2010-05-20 17:25:20,809 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager] - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not insert: [com.edde.Book]; SQL [/* insert com.edde.Book */ insert into Book (author, bookName, publication) values (?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.edde.Book]
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:629)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:683)
 at com.edde.BookDao.insertBook(BookDao.java:18)
 at com.edde.BookServiceImpl.saveBook(BookServiceImpl.java:34)
 at com.edde.Test.main(Test.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.edde.Book]
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
 at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2329)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2836)
 at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:705)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:693)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:689)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:686)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
 ... 5 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'edde.book' doesn't exist
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2696)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2105)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2398)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2316)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2301)
 at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
 ... 23 more
```

Now my question is: **how to create the table automatically?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` and not `hbm2ddl.auto`.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

```
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
</props>
```

Comment: @Yousui, did you add the `hibernate.` prefix to the property name?